# A floating does not work properly

Tags: html, css

There are some menu items with floating `left` property. But if I make screen small then one of the menu items (which is named `Игнорлист` e.g. third from the left) does not fully stick to left side.

Why is this?

This looks like

[image]

Comment: I cannot see the menu item unless logged in. You will need to post the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using float, try inline-block.

```
.link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide **width** to the main div. Since the div doesn't have enough width its pushing the element to the next line.

> Width:1024px;

Comment: That is probably unnecessary and not a good solution.